# Anyone have any impressions, hints, tutorials from developing for Google Android devices?

Tags: android, sdk

I have a `T-Mobile G1` and I'm going to download the developer SDK and see if I can create a few simple apps for my phone.  If you've done similar development, please answer below and tell me about your experience.  Please share any links you found especially useful.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't find the SDK documents to be all that helpful, at least at first.  What really got be started was looking through the example chapters of **The Busy Coder's Guide to Android** from CommonsWare.  You can find this [on the book's website](http://commonsware.com/Android/index.html).  The code examples for the book are also provided at that link.

The example code provided in those examples, plus the example code included in the SDK gave me a good idea of where to start.  I'm still not totally solid on a lot of things, but development is going a lot faster than it was beforehand.

One thing you definitely want to be sure you do is watch the videos provided by Google.  The application life cycle for Android is much different than a traditional application, so you want to make sure you understand was Intents, Views, and Content Providers are.  These videos can all be seen on YouTube in [this playlist](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=8D19D01A9F4AA199).

The last helpful resource I can point you to is the blogging community.  Every now and then, [Planet Android](http://planetandroid.com/) and [Hello Android](http://helloandroid.com/) have code excerpts from the blogs they aggregate. [Jeffrey Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/) is big into Android development and has released some useful code on his blog.

Android development currently is much like shooting in the dark, but it will hopefully take off soon and provide us with more valuable resources!  I know there are [a](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210648) [few](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071599886) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356174) out there.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

The biggest thing I recommend is to make sure you really understand the lifecycle of android apps. Many apps are put out there which crash or perform badly (or make the entire phone run poorly) because they are not designed to follow the application lifecycle properly.

For simple apps it's nothing to worry about but soon you might want to run something in the background (play music, etc), or need to save your state if the user switches apps. It's tricky but makes sense once you see some examples.

You might also check out some of the Android sessions from the Google I/O developer conference in May:

- [An Introduction to Android](http://sites.google.com/site/io/an-introduction-to-android)
- [Building an Android Application 101](http://sites.google.com/site/io/building-an-android-application)
- [Anatomy & Physiology of an Android](http://sites.google.com/site/io/anatomy--physiology-of-an-android)

Answer (score 5):

I started from here

http://code.google.com/android/kb/commontasks.html

I got my environment and emulator up and running within about 15 minutes.

First impressions are its fun to work with.

Paul

Answer (score 3):

I found the [notepad tutorial](http://code.google.com/android/intro/tutorial.html) extremely helpful in understanding the basics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also beginning to get my feet wet with android development. Honestly, I think some of the books out there do a pretty good job of explaining the development framework and getting you started with using the tools quickly. Some of the books I'm reading include "Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours" (obviously the title is an exaggeration; the book is just organized into hours. Each hour will take some time for a beginner), "Hello, Android: Introducing Google's Mobile Development Platform (3rd edition)", and "Beginning Android 2." From my, so far, limited experience, developing using the SDK is accessible and enjoyable. That being said, you really need to commit the time/energy to get up to speed.